# How can I conditionally change css styles with js?

Tags: javascript, css

I'd like to implement some javascript that uses an if statement to change some css styles.  Not sure how to do it, any help would be great!

Comment: Do you want to change all the relevant elements that are associated with a css declaration on the page or just a single element?

Comment: just a single element @jeff

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you change the attached CSS file with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086973/how-can-you-change-the-attached-css-file-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change a single style of an element using JavaScript, use

```
document.getElementById(id).style.property = new style
```

eg :

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.color= "red";
```

To add a new CSS class to an element, use

```
document.getElementById(id).classList.add("mystyle");
```

To remove

```
document.getElementById(id).classList.remove("mystyle");
```

Demo :

```js
function changeSingleStyle() {
  var color = document.getElementById("myDiv").style.color;
  if (color === "red")
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.color = "yellow";
  else
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.color = "red";
}
function addClass() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.add("mystyle");
}
function removeClass() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.remove("mystyle");
}
```

```css
.mystyle {
  color : red;
  background: green;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"> This is a div </div>
<button onclick="changeSingleStyle()">changeSingleStyle</button>
<button onclick="addClass()">addClass</button>
<button onclick="removeClass()">removeClass</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to change CSS using JavaScript, the syntax looks like the following:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.property = new style
```

For example, if you want to change the *display* property of an element with id = "container" to block, it would be:

```
document.getElementById("container").style.display = "block";
```

Given this, you could easily add an IF statement depending on what condition you want. For example:

```
if(condition)
{
     document.getElementById("container").style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function barHtml (percent) {
        
 return `
       <div class= "${percent>25 ? "class1":" class2"}"
          style="width: ${percent}%;">
      </div>`
    }
```

document.body.innerHTML=`<div>${barHtml(20)}</div>`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31490263)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `.style.property` or `.style.cssText`

```js
function myStyleFunction() {
  document.getElementById('styled').style.color = 'red';
}

function myStyleFunctionCssText() {
  document.getElementById('styled2').style.cssText = 'color: lime';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myStyleFunction();" id="styled">
  Style with .style.color
</button>

<button onclick="myStyleFunctionCssText();" id="styled2">
  Style with .style.cssText
</button>
```

With this code, the button on the left will go red, the one on the right will go lime.

You can also do this easily with jQuery.

```js
function myStyleFunction() {
  $(".style").css("color", "magenta");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="style" onclick="myStyleFunction();">Style by class</button>

<button class="style">Style by class 2</button>
```

This code changes all elements in the classes color to magenta if you click the first button.