# Is it common to assign class attribute to <link>? What is it's effect?

Tags: html

I've inspected the code of https://highlightjs.org/.

In between the ... i've found a suspicous class attribute assigned to a  tag. For example:

```
<link class="codestyle" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles/default.css" disabled="">
```

Google and the MDN truned out to be not helpful. Instead the MDN didn't even list the class attribute as possible attribute for a  tag.

Does it have any effect?

Comment: Adding a class to an element classifies it as belonging to that class, period. That is _all_ a class _ever_ does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it okay to add id/class to <link> tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077475/is-it-okay-to-add-id-class-to-link-tag)

Comment: "Instead the MDN didn't even list the class attribute as possible attribute for a tag." That's because the class attribute can be applied to any element, so it would be redundant to list it for all elements.

Comment: As mentioned at the top of the attributes section: http://note.io/1syJpCp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it common to assign class attribute to `<link>`?

No.

> What is it's effect?

The same as for any other element.

It makes it a member of a class so it can be identified as part of a group by languages/apis that include a means to access elements via their class (such as CSS, DOM and XPath).

Answer (score 1):

It's there to make it easier to query alternate stylesheets in the script that switches style of a snippet. Look at line #14 of the page source.