# Can you use IDs with HTML head tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I think the answer is probably "no," but I wanted to get the opinion of people who know a lot more than me.  Can you use the "id" attribute with HTML elements in the head section, such as title or link?  The purpose would be to change their values with JavaScript.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it okay to add id/class to <link> tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077475/is-it-okay-to-add-id-class-to-link-tag)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. All HTML elements support the ID attribute.

See [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes):

> The following attributes are common to and may be specified on all HTML elements (even those not defined in this specification):
>
> …
>
> - `id`

Comment: Update Dec 2020: That list no longer explicitly mentions `id`, which made me think that it was removed. But `id` is still globally supported, it's now mentioned in a paragraph below the list: `The class, id, and slot attributes may be specified on all HTML elements.`

Answer (score 1):

Yup.
Every html element supports an id:

```
<head id="everyone"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `id` attribute is a [Global Attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Yes, you can use an `id` attribute in a `head` element. Further, here is the full list of Global Attributes and they may be specified on all [HTML elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#html-elements).

- accesskey
- class
- contenteditable
- dir
- hidden
- id
- lang
- spellcheck
- style
- tabindex
- title
- translate

Comment: From your link: *This document has been discontinued and is only made available for historical purposes.* It is out of date and has never been normative. Please don't use it.